# Correct way to define state in StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Problem: build() depends in `StatefulWidget's` state**

Recently I moved a property inspector widget from being an always visible part of the UI to a `Drawer`.

Once I moved the property inspector, the app rendered random update operations regarding the object when the property inspector was about to edit values: The property inspector updated a random other `object`, not the current 'focus' `object`.

**Solution : Make build() depend on the `State<T>` of `StatefulWidget`**

I solved the issue by making the `State<PropertyInspector>` solely depend on state variables defined inside `State<PropertyInspector>` itself - instead of defining state variables in `StatefulWidget` and accessing these variables using `widget.<someVariable>`.

Root cause of the problem seems to be the fact that the Property Inspector in the `Drawer` gets more updates from the framework than the permanently visible alternative.

**General advice**

In general, Flutter needs to insert / remove / update `StatefulWidget` at various moments of time. **While `StatefulWidget` might change, its `State<T>` object persists.**

Thus, the `build()` method of a `StatefulWidget` should depend on `State<T>` - and not on the changing `StatefulWidget`.

**Rules of thumb**

- All instance variables of `StatefulWidget` **should be final**
- Thus, if an instance variable of `StatefulWidget` can't be marked as final, the design of the `StatefulWidget` is wrong.
- From within `State<T>`, access to `'widget.*'` instance variables are fine, as long as those variables are final.
- Instance variables of `State<T>` **may be non-final**

Is my description correct?

[This site](https://www.flutterbeads.com/pass-data-to-stateful-widget-in-flutter/) doesn't warn about using state as `widget.*`. ***Isn't that wrong? or at least dangerous / bad style?***

As far as I understand, the proposed state in `StatefulWidget` might work fine for some time. But, under different conditions, it is likely to render problems (as mine).

Helpful video [How Stateful Widgets Are Used Best - Flutter Widgets 101 Ep. 2](https://youtu.be/AqCMFXEmf3w) in Flutter's [StatefulWidget class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) documentation.

**Contradiction**

This lint error contradicts my explanation: [no_logic_in_create_state](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/no_logic_in_create_state.html)

### Update

I'd be happy if answers would explain, if this description / practice is correct or not.

I established this practice since certain widgets didn't behave as expected in some projects.

Comment: Can you provide concrete example or code?  It is not a problem if you use one of `StatefulWidget` or `State` to control the widget state if you use it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your description properly then I would say your rules of thumb are correct. The state class and fields persist across renders, therefore any mutable state should be enclosed within the state class not within the widget class.

The lint no_logic_in_create_state doesn't contradict this, the lint is saying no logic in the create state method, which is in the widget class.

Any mutable field in the widget class could be reset when the widget re-renders and therefore no mutable state should be kept in any widget.

I will also add that just because an instance variable in a widget is final doesn't mean it wont change within the lifecycle of the app. If you pass a prop into the widget then the instance variable would update if the prop updates (the widget would be recreated but the state wouldn't).